# Изменить качество изображения или ресайз php

Tags: php, upload

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код, который грузит файл на сервер.

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/home/uploads/contacts/';
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_POST['file_name'] . '.jpg'))
{
    print "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
} else {
    print "There some errors!";
}
?>
```

Как установить качество этой загружаемой фотографии на 0 либо изменить размер этого изображения на нужный?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php

Comment: Вы предлагаете написать Вам код?

Comment: @Дмитрий помочь составить код.

Answer (score 0):

http://rgho.st/6KYtKQsbH используйте этот класс для работы с изображениями

```
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load('old.png'); // путь к файлу
$image->resize(332, 187); //установка размера
$image->save('new.png', 80); // сохранение, первый аргумент: путь/имя выходного файла, второй аргумент: качество изображения
```

Comment: В PHP есть замечательное расширение для работы с изображениями [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php)

Comment: @Evgeny тогда напишите ответ с примером. я посоветовал и показал наглядно то что я использую.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

$image = new Imagick($tmpFile);
$image->thumbnailImage(400, 400); // Изменяем размер изображения
$image->writeImage('путь, куда сохранить файл');
```

**P.S.** предварительно прочтите инструкцию по настройке [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php), а также примеры различных режимов редактирования [тут](http://www.phpimagick.com/Imagick/thumbnailImage)